# How to find suitable manual exposure settings based on the light and subject?

Tags: exposure, low-light, manual-mode

I'm using Canon 700d with 18-55mm and 55-250mm Kit lenses.
Somedays my camera manual settings suits the environment and I'm able get some great shots.(Sea shore,Road,Terrace).
But sometime I'm getting blurred, dark very poor shots, I tried with shooting many different setting but nothing helps.low-light(Indoor, using flash, evening).
While I try to focus a subject it produces a brighter preview image but the resultant image is darker that it shown in preview.
How to calculate the suitable aperture, shutter speed, ISO and white balance for the lighting condition and the subject.
I do use tripod wherever necessary.
Please advise.

Comment: Does this camera not have internal metering?  If so, it should do most of this itself.

Comment: I suggest you read [What is the "exposure triangle"?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/what-is-the-exposure-triangle) and then edit your question to concentrate on the things you don't understand *after* reading that question. But as Olin says, the first thing to do is to leave everything on auto (or Program Mode) and let the camera do the difficult work for you.

Comment: I tried with Auto or Program mode.It added too much noise and looks poor.

Comment: So, after reading the linked question, do you understand why your camera decided on the settings it did? If so, edit your question to explain what you still need help with. If you don't, probably best to read that question again because it has some excellent answers.

Comment: Yes @PhilipKendall I read.I already have enough knowledge on how ISO,Shutter speed and aperture influence the quality of the photo.But this post has given me some more ideas..And finally the problem is with my camera combo and I have to purchase a prime lens.

Comment: Yes @OlinLathrop It does have metering.Can you please refer me some articles to get more familiar on how metering mode influence the picture quality.

Comment: There's no reason to go buy a prime. You mention that you have a tripod - so use it. ISO100 for low noise, f/whatever for depth of field, and set the shutter out as long as you need it to be. The only reason you would need a prime is to get larger apertures because you want to shoot faster shutter speeds...in which case you should mention this in your question.

Comment: What is your question, precisely? As written, the question is unfocused, leading to a discussion in these comments. Stack Exchange is not suited to back-and-forth discussion of an evolving question.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you need to understand the "exposure triangle". In any given situation you can use these variables (aperture, shutter speed and ISO) to modify the final image. As you only have kit lenses (slow in terms of max aperture), you need to compromise often, set your aperture as wide as possible and you're limited to adjusting shutter speed and ISO.

Shooting in low light requires one (or more) of these things:

- larger aperture (preferably f/1.8 or lower, impossible with your kit lenses)
- slower shutter speed (which would result in blurry images if you're shooting moving subjects)
- higher ISO (your images will be noisy)

You can also of course add more light (strobes, flash, wait till morning), but adding more light is very situational and the result won't always be what you want as you're modifying the light and the mood of the shot. If not balanced correctly it will produce very unnatural look (think deer in spotlights kinda of look).

Your combo simply isn't suited well for low light photography. If you want to shoot often in bad lighting conditions, you need a fullframe sensor + fast lens (1.8 or faster). Fullframe can perform in higher ISO much better and fast lens will let much more light in for your sensor to capture.

There's really no way around it, you can't fool physics. Photography is all about painting with light.

Comment: You've missed out what is potentially the most important thing if shooting in low light: add light.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, as he's talking about situations when there's not enough light and he knows there's not enough light, I suppose he wanted to help with camera settings in such situation, but you're right, added it to the answer. The biggest problem with adding more light though is it's not possible every time and it's hard to balance to preserve the natural light. If he wants to shoot a party during a night and he adds a huge light, sure, he will be able to take the shot, but it will be probably different to what he originally intended as a result.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, the answer is mostly aimed for shooting when you can't (or don't want to) alter the lighting for whatever reason.